# optimize a nested for loop in R, using apply?

Tags: r, for-loop, apply

I would like optimize the following nested for loop, which  iterates over select set of columns in a dataframe and checks if it corresponds to values/strings from a vector:

```
Positions=c()
for (col in vectorCols ) {
    for (code in vectorCodes ){
      Positions<- c(Positions,which(as.numeric(df[,col])==code))
    }
```

The dataframe is quite big, with 800,000 rows. vectorCodes can be 100 items long and about 20 selected columns (out of 2000).

i also tried something like the following, but it didn't help

```
  FunctionGrepCol<-function(col){
    Positions <- unlist( lapply( vectorCodes , function(x) (Positions,which(as.numeric(df[,col])==x)) ) )
  }
  Positions <-unlist(lapply(vectorCols, FunctionGrepCol ))
```

is there a way to combine put the nested for loop in an apply function to optimize it?

Comment: Can you post small example input and expected output? Hard to provide working code based on what you provided here.

Comment: `which` is vectorized already, so not sure why you are looping for it at all. For example: `x <- sample(1:10, 100, replace = TRUE);  which(x %in% c(2, 3))`

Comment: I noticed that %in% was slower than a for loop, but I don't have actual timings, I will try to time them.

edit: Hm, okay that is indeed much faster, I don't know why i thought a for loop was faster in this case. Thanks very much.

Comment: `system.time(for (j in 1:1000000) for (i in 1:10) which(x == i))
   user  system elapsed 
 25.020   4.446  29.569`; 
`system.time(for (j in 1:1000000) which(x %in% 1:10))
   user  system elapsed 
  7.240   1.175   8.439`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this solution, instead of looping through the columns names and subsetting, you can subset your data frame firstly and then loop through it just like a list.

```
Positions <- unlist(lapply(df[, vectorCols], function(col) which(col %in% vectorCodes)))
```